# How do I enable editing features in Sitecore page editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm using Sitecore 7.2 and trying to allow a user to set things like datasources and some custom parameters on sublayouts in page editor mode. The user is a member of sitecore\Designer and sitecore\Author, but when that user tries to edit the component properties, the fields appear grayed out/disabled.

[image: Screenshot]

I am able to enable these options by setting a user as an admin, but don't want to grant quite that much power to this particular user.

Comment: Your screenshot has an access denied.  Do the users have access to write to the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how tried it and it works on Sitecore 7.2

1. Create a new user called ***cbarnes*** (and in your case if there are other content editors)
2. Create a new Role - call it say ***SP Content Editor Authoring***
3. Make that role a member of *sitecore\Author* and *sitecore\Designer*. This way it inherits everything from those two roles.

[image]

4. Make the user ***cbarnes*** one of the members of that role.

[image]

5. Lastly go to the security editor and give **Write** permission on the item after selecting the SP Content Editor Authoring Role under Roles and Users section.

[image]

6. Login as cbarnes user and check if it work!

Let us know if this works for you. Happy Sitecoring!

Comment: Thanks @shriroop - i had some other permissions applied to the user's roles in question that i didn't realize before. Resetting things back to this fixed things for me.

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into this same issue today on a 7.2 project.  While my user had both the `sitecore\Designer` and `sitecore\Author` roles as a part of a client-specific author role I created, they were not able to edit rendering parameters.

By default, users in these roles have read-only access the `Sitecore\Templates` folder.  Within this folder I had an additional folder named "Rendering Parameters" where I stored all my rendering parameters templates. I added `Write` access to the client-specific role for my "Rendering Parameters" template folder and users in that role can now edit and save rendering parameters without elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Access Viewer" tool from Sitecore start menu to define why your user does not have required rights.

By default both roles *sitecore\Designer* and *sitecore\Author* have *field read* and *field write* access to Layout template section fields. But, it seems that roles have only read access to item that you are trying to edit. You can add write access to that item.

For more details look at [Security Administrator´s Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf)